# Spring Cloud Config Server Priority of Environment Variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a question regarding the priority of environment variables when working with [spring cloud config server](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_config)

In my service I have a local properties file `application.yml` with this content

```
foo:
  bar: "some"
  buz: "some"
  joe: "some"
```

The service is also connected to a config server with a configuration repository that contains a file `testservice-api.yml` (where `testservice-api` is the spring application name of the service). The contents of this file is:

```
foo:
  bar: "some-specific"
```

So with this setup the configuration at runtime would result in this:

```
{
    "foo.bar": "some-specific",
    "foo.buz": "some",
    "foo.joe": "some"
}
```

Now I try to override `foo.bar` and `foo.joe` with an environment variable.

So I start the service with this command:

`FOO_BAR=some-env FOO_JOE=some-env gradle bootRun`

From what I read in [this part of the spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) the environment variables should have priority over the configuration files - also the spring cloud config documentation does not state sth different - so I would expect the result to be:

```
{
    "foo.bar": "some-env",
    "foo.buz": "some",
    "foo.joe": "some-env"
}
```

But instead I get:

```
{
    "foo.bar": "some-specific",
    "foo.buz": "some",
    "foo.joe": "some-env"
}
```

So only the configuration from the local configuration file inside the jar is overridden by the environment variable - the property from the config repo seems to have priority over the environment variable.

Is this explainable - Or is this a bug? Any hints in this one?

Please find the example code here:

https://github.com/mduesterhoeft/configserver-test

The README in the repository lists the issue described here as [Use Case 3](https://github.com/mduesterhoeft/configserver-test#use-case-3----override-properties-with-environment-variables)

Comment: Config Server has the highest priority.

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for the hint - it that documented somewhere? All I found is "These are the same rules as apply in a standalone Spring Boot application." - so I thought these rules apply - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config

Comment: It should be if it's not, but it would be in spring cloud documentation.

Comment: @spencergibb I tried this one http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.3/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_config.  All statements regarding precedence read as if the normal spring boot behaviour applies.

Comment: For the normal boot properties, config server takes precedence over those.

Comment: This [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#overriding-bootstrap-properties) seems to include a section about overriding config server properties.

Answer (score 13):

define following properties in git repo (as a source for config-server) [for given profile]:

  `spring.cloud.config:
    overrideSystemProperties: false
    overrideNone: true`

keep in mind properties (especially overrideSystemProperties & overrideNone) in bootsrap.yml are overriden by those from config-server by default

Comment: Just FYI, for me this worked when I put it in the git repo config file for the individual application (the config client) and didn't work when I put it in the git repo config file for the config server

Comment: After some thought, I realized that it is cool that it is possible to do this, BUT, it is probably not a good idea. The whole point of pulling in a *centralized* config component is to gain just that - *centralized* config. If you start allowing it to become *distributed* config, there are 101 ways things are going to to wrong. Consider what happens if you need to change an API key, that was supplied via env var. You will need to restart the service. What point is there then to config server? Use with caution!

Comment: There are variables that MUST be injected by overriding the config-server. For example, imagine that you have a Kubernetes deployment that points to a Service with a dynamic name (changes everytime the Helm chart is deployed). The configserver will never know the right name and it would be awful to have to manually change the configuration everytime the dynamic name changes. Though, it could be done with a Jenkins pipeline that changes the code of the repository and commits, it is too complex.