# server.port in command line not working with spring cloud config server and eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am studying spring could. What I have now is a spring cloud config server and eureka server.

Code for Config Server

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=config-server
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/vincentwah/spring-cloud-config-repository/
server.port=7001
```

Code for Eureka server

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

bootstrap.properties

```
spring.application.name=eureka-server
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:7001/
```

The config for eureka-server is https://github.com/vincentwah/spring-cloud-config-repository/blob/master/eureka-server.properties

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:${server.port}/eureka/
server.port=1111
```

When I start eureka server, I'd like to change the port, so I run below command

```
java -jar target/eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=1234
```

However, the server is still started with port 1111

```
2017-01-03 14:04:11.324  INFO 6352 --- [      Thread-10] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Changing status to UP
2017-01-03 14:04:11.339  INFO 6352 --- [      Thread-10] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server
2017-01-03 14:04:11.492  INFO 6352 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 1111 (http)
2017-01-03 14:04:11.493  INFO 6352 --- [           main] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Updating port to 1111
2017-01-03 14:04:11.500  INFO 6352 --- [           main] com.example.EurekaServerApplication      : Started EurekaServerApplication in 27.532 seconds (JVM running for 29.515)
```

I think I am not doing wrong with --server.port in command line. Does anybody encounter same issue?

Comment: Which OS? Try `--SERVER_PORT=1234`.

Comment: Windows 7 + spring boot 1.4.3 .  I have tried --SERVER_PORT=1234 , but not working.   I have source code at https://github.com/vincentwah/spring-boot/tree/master/config-server  and https://github.com/vincentwah/spring-boot/tree/master/eureka-server

Comment: Just noticed that you retrieve the properties from the config server... If I recall correctly those do take precedence over other defined properties.

Comment: As mentioned by https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-3/config-server/configuration-clients.html , "Properties from a Config Server will override those defined locally" .  But it also mentioned by https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html , "command line properties always take precedence over other property sources"  , so if I use config server, then there is no way to dynamically change the server.port?

Comment: Hmm... The question is is `--server.port` a command line argument or is `-Dserver.port` that. Also Spring Cloud takes precedence here (everything that Spring Boot does, is basically what falls into the category *defined locally*).

Comment: I tried all of these, --server.port and -Dserver.port and --SERVER_PORT as well. None of them working.  But I found if I create multiple profile properties and put server.port into the profile properties, when start, I use --spring.profiles.active=profile, then I can get the correct profile loaded and the server.port is exactly what I have put into the profile.  This is also a command line input, not sure why this works but the --server.port not.

Comment: The profile is a bit special and is also used to tell the config server to load additional properties (just like Spring Boot would do).

Answer (score 6):

Spring Cloud Config, by default, overrides local configuration. It is meant to be the source of truth. You could use profiles so the port is not defined with a particular profile. You could also disable the config client if it's not really needed (in tests for example).

There are also options to [allow overrides](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR3/#overriding-bootstrap-properties).

> The property sources that are added to you application by the
>   bootstrap context are often "remote" (e.g. from a Config Server), and
>   by default they cannot be overridden locally, except on the command
>   line. If you want to allow your applications to override the remote
>   properties with their own System properties or config files, the
>   remote property source has to grant it permission by setting
>   `spring.cloud.config.allowOverride=true` (it doesn’t work to set this
>   locally). Once that flag is set there are some finer grained settings
>   to control the location of the remote properties in relation to System
>   properties and the application’s local configuration:
>   `spring.cloud.config.overrideNone=true` to override with any local
>   property source, and
>   `spring.cloud.config.overrideSystemProperties=false` if only System
>   properties and env vars should override the remote settings, but not
>   the local config files.

Comment: Also please note this point about decentralizing the configurations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316835/spring-cloud-config-server-priority-of-environment-variables/38658710#comment73581084_38658710

Answer (score 0):

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:${server.port}/eureka/
server.port=1111
spring.cloud.config.allowOverride=true
spring.cloud.config.overrideNone=true
spring.cloud.config.overrideSystemProperties=false
```

This is working.